# Redirect R Shiny to local host after oauth token authentication for Azure AD

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am creating a Shiny app that involves AAD token authentication to connect to Snowflake.

I am using a .js script below that obtains the token:

```
async function wrapperFunc() {
                const msalConfig = {
                    auth: {
                        clientId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
                        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXX'
                    }
                };

                const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

                const silentRequest = {
                    scopes: ["api://XXXXXX/session:role-any"]
                    
                };

                const callLogin = async function(silentRequest, msalInstance) {
                    try {
                        const loginResponse = await msalInstance.loginPopup(silentRequest);
                        return loginResponse;
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                }

                response = callLogin(silentRequest, msalInstance);
        return response;
}
wrapperFunc().then(result => {
        Shiny.setInputValue("oauthToken", result['accessToken']);
                console.log(result['accessToken']);
});
```

and then plugging that token into the following db connection:

```
pii_db_connection <- function(OAuth_token) {
  connection <- DBI::dbConnect(
    drv = odbc::odbc(),
    dsn = "snowflake",
    token = OAuth_token,
    authenticator = "oauth"
  )
  return(connection)
}
```

I am redirected to the browser window to log in, and then once that's done, I get hit with this error message:

```
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'XXXXX' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'XXXXX'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal.
```

I can access the app by changing the URL to a localhost URL. But my question is, can I get it to automatically redirect the browser window to the localhost URL?

Comment: My guess is that the javascript is using the localhost's "real" hostname instead of `localhost`, in which case the redirection should fail (since OAuth relies on specificity). I don't know how to resolve that, but perhaps you can dive into a js-console and see what hostname is being sent to/from the oauth endpoint.

Comment: you may need to update the "redirectUri" field in your msalConfig to match the localhost URL that you specified in the Azure portal